# How do i write the following function with the >>= operator

Tags: haskell, monads

How do I write this function using the >>= operator?

```
parseNumber2 :: Parser LispVal
parseNumber2 = do x <- many1 digit
                  return $ (Number . read) x
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A straightforward desugaring of the do-notation gives

```
parseNumber2 :: Parser LispVal
parseNumber2 = many1 digit >>= (return . Number . read)
```

but the more idiomatic way is to use `fmap` or the equivalent `<$>` operator from `Control.Applicative`

```
parseNumber2 = Number . read <$> many1 digit
```

**To desugar do-notation:**

1. Flip any `<-` bindings over to the right side and add `>>=` and a lambda abstraction

   ```
   do x <- a
      y <- b
      ...
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   a >>= \x ->
   b >>= \y ->
   ...
   ```
2. For any non-binding forms, add a `>>` on the right:

   ```
   do a
      b
      ...
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   a >>
   b >>
   ...
   ```
3. Leave the last expression alone.

   ```
   do a
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   a
   ```

Applying these rules to your code, we get

```
parseNumber2 =
    many1 digit >>= \x -> 
    return $ (Number . read) x
```

Do some simplifications

```
parseNumber2 = many1 digit >>= \x -> (return . Number . read) x
parsenumber2 = many1 digit >>= (return . Number . read)
```

Now, for any monad, `fmap` or `<$>` can be defined as

```
f <$> x = x >>= (return . f)
```

Use this to get the idiomatic form

```
parseNumber2 = Number . read <$> many1 digit
```

Comment: See also [RWH # Desugaring of do blocks](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html#monads.do) and [Haskell 2010 > Expressions # Do](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14)